# Getting html data-* attribute from another link in the same outer container

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

Below is the HTML code that generates a section with one specific product from a woocommerce product list. I have put a **function directLink()** in the **fist link** it so I can redirect a person to a page using "data-product_sku" from the **last link** of that section.

From the click even I have only mananged to find that particular link on the page but I can't get the data-product_sku data from it except just parsing it as a string but I'm sure there is way to find it directly with javascript.

html:

```
<li class="post-2028">
  <a href="http:..." class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">
    <span onclick="directLink(event); return false;">
      First Link
    </span>
    <div itemprop="description">
    <p>...Product Description...</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http:..." data-quantity="1" data-product_id="2028" data-product_sku="323">
    Last Link
  </a>
</li>
```

js:

```
function directLink(e) {
    var elmnt = e.path[2].children[1];
}
```

I get

```
elmnt = '<a href="http:..." data-quantity="1" data-product_id="2028" data-product_sku="323">Last Link</a>'
```

I also have tried:

```
var elmnt = e.path[2].children[1];
$(elmnt).data('product_sku');
```

but that gives *undefined*

How can I get that attribute by js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chould do the following:

```
e.path[2].children[1].dataset.product_sku
```

will return what are you expecting `323`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the .attr() method. Try something like

```
    $(elmnt).attr('data_product_sku');
```

Alternatively, this doesn't require jQuery. Using pure JavaScript, this would look like

```
    elmnt.getAttribute('data_product_sku');
```